# Silex - can't use session on post request

Tags: php, session, silex

Hey I have problem with set session on post requests. For example, get request working corectly. I have tried to redirect after post request but this doesn't work too. There are the sections of my code;

Not working:

```
$app->post(
    '/localauth',
    'UserController::serviceLoginAuth'
)
->after(
    function() {
        session_name('auth')
        session_start();
    }
);
```

Working only without redirect in serviceLoginAuth:

```
// redirect to '/authsuccess'    
$app->post('/localauth', 'UserController::serviceLoginAuth');
$app->get('/authsuccess', 'UserController::serviceLoginAuthSuccess');
```

I use http post with angular code:

```
        $http({
      url: apiConst.apiurl+'/localauth',
      method: "POST",
      data: $.param({
        login: user.login,
        pass:user.pass
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
      }
  }).then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
      $cookies.put('csrftoken',response.data.token);
    }).catch(function(){
      console.log(err);
     });
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you getting any sort of errors?

Comment: Without this headers im getting http code 405 and options error. But this headers fix this error but i cant send session after post.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use silex [SessionServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/session.html#sessionserviceprovider) ?

The problem can be that you are calling session_start on a Middleware using `->after` instead of `->before`?

Comment: yes i have tryed before with no effect. Same as tryed SessionServiceProvider. $app->get() working perfectly but post() have some problems.

Comment: So you are trying to redirect from $app->get('/authsuccess') to $app->post('/localauth')?

Comment: No I'm trying redirect from $app->post('localauth') to $app->get('authsuccess') and i still cant pass session. Only if i go to stricte 'authsuccess' then session is registered.